# Highcharts yAxis Categories with string values: error 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

Right off the bat here is the desired chart in ChartJS.
We have two x-axes. One showing power from a meter and the other showing meter state over time (open, closed, or in standby) In both datasets the X axis is Unix time. The power Y axis is numerical and the state x axis is one of the three state categories. Both are drawn in lines.
[image: Desired Chart rendered with ChartJS]

To get right to the point: how do I do this in Highcharts? I have the second axis set up:

```
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: [
          {
            title: {
              text: 'Real Power'
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'category', //I have also removed this line 
            title: {
              text: 'state'
            },
            categories: ['closed', 'standby', 'open']
          }
        ],
```

Any attempt to set the Y axis value to a string in highcharts results in a well known: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/14/

Furthermore online I only seem to find categories on the X axis. Any help getting to the right place is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/b7Lf9kp5/, also, the data. It is an array of arrays like `[1543847400000,46.12,46.24,45.3,46.21,163210000]`. When you work on it, edit the question with a working example from jsfiddle or codesandbox. We can help you easily with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a string as `x` value, use a number instead, for example:

```
    series: [{
        ...
    }, {
        ...,
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [1, 0, 2, 1]
    }],
    yAxis: [{
        ...
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'state'
        },
        categories: ['closed', 'standby', 'open'],
        min: 0,
        max: 2
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o7Lvyadm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis